# função ajax retorna [OBJECT OBJECT]

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Bom dia galera.
Estou com um problema.

Montei uma função pra trazer uns resultados no Onchange de um select 
via ajax

Oproblema é que nesse input 'qtde' esta printando a seguinte msg [OBJECT OBJECT]

Alquem sabe me dizer oq esta errado??

segue o codigo =>

```
function setqtde(obj)
 {
   var item = obj.value;
   $.ajax({
    url:BASE_URL+"estoque/pegaqtde",
    type:'GET',
    data:{valor:item},
    dataType:'json',
    success:function(json)
    {

      document.getElementById("qtde").value = json;
    }
  });
 }
```

Comment: json é um objeto. Você tem que usar `json.campo` onde campo é a propriedade que contém a quantidade

Comment: Depende do conteudo do jQuery, depende do que fez do bakc-end, depende de muita coisa para termos o minimo de noção de como te ajudar, até o momento esta inviavel/impossivel imaginar a origem do problema, só te digo, a URL esta retornando um JSON como resposta e JSON não pode ser imprimido como string diretamente e nem é o que você deseja, vc claramente quer algo do json especifico, mas da forma que esta pergunta não somos capazes de adivinhar nada. Então dê detalhes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Insira um `console.log(json)` em seu retorno do json, pois ele é retornado como um objeto, por meio do console será possivel ver os atributos do objeto. Assim, é só acessar a propriedade do objeto retornada desejada como: `json.propriedade`

Answer (score -1):

Deu certo pessoal
a propriedade que eu precisava acessar era a quantidade

coloquei     json.quantidade; ai deu certo!

valeu galera pelas respotas.